# ECSlidingViewController with UITabBarController

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have a requirement where I need to slide the view but thats inside a UITabBarController.

Does any one tried doing that ? ECSlidingViewController works perfect if I make it rootViewController but I want that in UITabBarController.

I tried setting the ECSlidingViewController as one of the view controllers for the UITabBarController but it keeps crashing after the first swipe or some times it goes in infinite loop

Below is my code

```
    myWorkController = [[TaskWorkViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WorkViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil]; // This is the controller where I have my specific logic

    myWorkNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myWorkController] autorelease]; // setting the myWorkController to UINavigationController as I need to navigate from this view controller to different view on specific actions
```

//SlidingviewController setup
        self.slidingViewController = [ECSlidingViewController slidingWithTopViewController:myWorkNavController];

```
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController = myWorkNavController;
    [myWorkNavController.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
    self.slidingViewController.anchorRightPeekAmount  = 100.0;
    myWorkController.slidingViewController = self.slidingViewController;

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = @[ self.slidingViewController, createNavController, currentWorkNavController];
```

and I am setting the **underRightViewController** inside myWorkController

```
 if (self.slidingViewController != nil)
    {

        UIViewController *underRightViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        // configure under right view controller
        underRightViewController.view.layer.borderWidth     = 0;
        underRightViewController.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
        underRightViewController.view.layer.borderColor     = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
        underRightViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout     = UIRectEdgeTop | UIRectEdgeBottom | UIRectEdgeRight; // don't go under the top view
        self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController = underRightViewController;
    }
```

1) First swipe works perfect but the second swipe breaks in ECSlidingViewController code
2) As I am using UINavigationController, when I try to change underRightViewController it fails at     [oldUnderRightViewController removeFromParentViewController]; of ECSlidingViewController code

Can some one please guide me what I am doing wrong or if this is possible with ECSlidingViewController

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should be possible, but I haven't tried it. What is the crash and where does it occur?

Comment: It goes into infinite loop in method updateTopViewGestures at if ([self.customAnchoredGesturesViewMap objectForKey:self.panGesture]) with error error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x60000010).